# Как сделать выезд блока по кривой Безье?

Tags: html, jquery

Сейчас анимация появления блока у меня реализована достаточно просто . Это обычное появление. А можно ли как-то реализовать выезд блока более эффектно? Типа плашка приехала, пошатнулась остановилась. И например пошатнулась и уехала . Подскажете реально ли такое реализовать на jquery? и что для этого нужно ?

Вот , что есть у меня сейчас :

```
     $(document).ready(function() {

        var tgl = 1
        $(".On_seorch_interface").click(function() {
                if (tgl !== 1) {
                    $(".serch_fild_block").hide()
                }


                if (tgl === 1) {
                    $(".serch_fild_block").show();
                    tgl = 0
                } else {
                    tgl = 1
                }

            )
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Лично я использую velocity.js можно сделать легкие, крутые анимации. Там отличная документация.

Comment: Старайтесь писать более развернутые ответы, добавьте пояснения, примеры, ссылки.

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте использовать к примеру СSS3 свойство transition

```
-webkit-transition: .4s cubic-bezier(0.420, 0.000, 1.000, 1.000);
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mayer/1Lb7ebhq/2/)

Отличный ресурс по функциям Безье: http://cubic-bezier.com/